# why these 2 charecters £ and ¬ is not being decoded correctly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, http, urlencode

I am working with an external api , and i wanted to test how it will accept special characters ... so i try sending the following value :-

```
!"£$%^&*()_+-=[]{},./;'[]#?:@~{};:\|¬`
```

which got saved inside the external system as follow:-

```
!"%u00a3$%^&*()_+-=[]{},./;'[]#?:@~{};:\|%u00ac`
```

which mean that the external api was not able to decode the `%u00a3` as `£` , and also was not able to decode the `%u00ac` as `¬` ?? while it were able to decode the other values correctly ... so is there a reason why it treated `£` and `¬` differently  ? in other word it could not decode these 2 charterers correctly?

second point. since my api does not support those types of characters,, so is there a way i can check if a string contain such values and display an error message to the users that they should not add these characters ?

Comment: how are you decoding them??

Comment: @Steve i am using  UriBuilder(apiurl); where the apiurl will contain the uri of the API and the passed parameters including the £ and ¬ values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external api probably uses the ASCII charset:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

As the characters `£` and `¬` do not exist in the ASCII charset, the api returned the unicode hexadecimal value for the characters (`%u` to indicate it is a unicode character and `00ac`, which is the hexadecimal value of the character `¬`).

It could also be a problem with the program you are sending the value or the way you are reading the string. Can't tell without further information.

Comment: this is a valid point i think ... so is there a way to prevent users from adding such values ?i mean can i check if a string contain non ASCII characters such as ¬ and £ and display an error message to the user ?

Comment: @johnG I really don't know much about c sharp or html, so you should ask that to someone else, or search if it has been answered in another question.